# Query to display all tablespaces in a database and datafiles

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to write a query to display all tablespaces in database suppose db and it's corresponding datafiles belong to user SCOTT. I can connect to SCOTT account and see it but I like to connect to sys as sysdba to see all tablespaces and datafiles belong to SCOTT.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-B28A7D79-24E3-49B5-B948-7C2277CB1FB8.htm#REFRN23287 and http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-0FA17297-73ED-4B5D-B511-103993C003D3.htm#REFRN23049

Comment: Neither databases, nor tablespaces nor data files belong to any user.  Are you coming to this from an MS SQL background?

Answer (score 33):

In oracle, generally speaking, there are number of facts that I will mention in following section:

- Each database can have many Schema/User (Logical division).
- Each database can have many tablespaces (Logical division).
- A schema is the set of objects (tables, indexes, views, etc) that belong to a user.
- In Oracle, a user can be considered the same as a schema.
- A database is divided into logical storage units called tablespaces, which group related logical structures together. For example, tablespaces commonly group all of an application’s objects to simplify some administrative operations. You may have a tablespace for application data and an additional  one for application indexes.

Therefore, your question, "to see all tablespaces and datafiles belong to SCOTT" is s bit wrong.

However, there are some DBA views encompass information about all database objects, regardless of the owner. Only users with DBA privileges can access these views:
DBA_DATA_FILES, DBA_TABLESPACES, DBA_FREE_SPACE, DBA_SEGMENTS.

So, connect to your DB as sysdba and run query through these helpful views.
For example this query can help you to find all tablespaces and their data files that objects of your user are located:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sgm.TABLESPACE_NAME , dtf.FILE_NAME
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS sgm
JOIN DBA_DATA_FILES dtf ON (sgm.TABLESPACE_NAME = dtf.TABLESPACE_NAME)
WHERE sgm.OWNER = 'SCOTT'
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to get a list of all tablespaces used in the current database instance, you can use the DBA_TABLESPACES view as shown in the following SQL script example:

```
SQL> connect SYSTEM/fyicenter
Connected.

SQL> SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, STATUS, CONTENTS
  2  FROM USER_TABLESPACES;
TABLESPACE_NAME                STATUS    CONTENTS
------------------------------ --------- ---------
SYSTEM                         ONLINE    PERMANENT
UNDO                           ONLINE    UNDO
SYSAUX                         ONLINE    PERMANENT
TEMP                           ONLINE    TEMPORARY
USERS                          ONLINE    PERMANENT
```

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/Show-All-Tablespaces-in-Current-Database.html

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT a.file_name,
       substr(A.tablespace_name,1,14) tablespace_name,
       trunc(decode(A.autoextensible,'YES',A.MAXSIZE-A.bytes+b.free,'NO',b.free)/1024/1024) free_mb,
       trunc(a.bytes/1024/1024) allocated_mb,
       trunc(A.MAXSIZE/1024/1024) capacity,
       a.autoextensible ae
FROM (
     SELECT file_id, file_name,
            tablespace_name,
            autoextensible,
            bytes,
            decode(autoextensible,'YES',maxbytes,bytes) maxsize
     FROM   dba_data_files
     GROUP BY file_id, file_name,
              tablespace_name,
              autoextensible,
              bytes,
              decode(autoextensible,'YES',maxbytes,bytes)
     ) a,
     (SELECT file_id,
             tablespace_name,
             sum(bytes) free
      FROM   dba_free_space
      GROUP BY file_id,
               tablespace_name
      ) b
WHERE a.file_id=b.file_id(+)
AND A.tablespace_name=b.tablespace_name(+)
ORDER BY A.tablespace_name ASC;
```

Comment: this works also for a pdbadmin

Answer (score -4):

Neither databases, nor tablespaces nor data files belong to any user. Are you coming to this from an MS SQL background?

```
select tablespace_name, 
       file_name
from dba_tablespaces
order by tablespace_name, 
         file_name;
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It does not work. Maybe you've tried to do this: `select a.tablespace_name, b.file_name from dba_tablespaces a join dba_data_files b on (a.tablespace_name=b.tablespace_name) order by tablespace_name;`